# Is Using Test-Only Maven Dependencies a Bad Practice?

Tags: maven, unit-testing

I have always been told that if your source code doesn't need a dependency, you shouldn't introduce a dependency just for unit tests (aside from unit test frameworks like JUnit). This actually makes a lot of sense since source code doesn't need that module, so your tests also shouldn't. Then, yesterday I saw a test dependency to another module that is not used in the source code but it defines a test suite in its unit tests and that test suite is used in the unit tests of other modules. This also made sense to me and considering Maven defines test scope for dependencies, it should be okay to define test-only dependencies. So I turned into Google but couldn't find any entry on this matter. **Is defining test-only dependencies bad or it is completely okay?** Or is it another situation based subject, where there is no clear answer?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, those questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. But I have no qualms answering it in a comment; the statement is completely and utterly bogus. It would mean you cannot use wonderful tools such as Mockito, Hamcrest, Wiremock or even Spring-test if you use the Spring framework. Whoever says such elitist things to you; nod politely, and ignore everything.

Comment: The whole concept of `scopes` is to enable using deps in context where you need them. This is not only true for `test` scope (on classpath in test and not otherwise) but also for other scopes, e.g. `runtime` (needed in runtime but not for compilation) or `provided` (needed only to compile but not in runtime). See "Dependecy Scope" at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` scope is exactly for this.

The dependency can be used for tests and will not be part of the final jar. So users of your jar will not see it in their dependency trees.

So feel free to add test frameworks at scope `test`.

Answer (score 1):

I would always try to keep dependencies only needed for testing (like JUnit) out of my final product. This also keeps your deployment smaller. So as long as long as nobody comes along with a convincing reason why not to do it, keep dependencies of to the scope that needs it.

By the way if such a convincing reason comes up, it's easy to change the configuration of your dependencies.

Like for code conventions I recommend to discuss this issue with the whole developer team and make a decision together.